# Sort values once by numbers and a second time by string

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I've got these values :

```
AH 18, AH 17, AH 16, AH 15, PE 18, PE 17, PE 16, PE 15... etc
```

I want to be able to sort them, by clicking on the appropriate button, to this order :

```
AH 18, PE 18, AH 17, PE 17, AH 16, PE 16, AH 15, PE 15
```

How can I achieve that? I know how to manipulate order using this code below, this works as it orders the values using numbers by removing the space and everything before using regex, but by doing that I get `PE 18, AH 18, PE 17, AH 17 ... etc` and not the right order I want it to be.

```
columnDefs.push({"type": "num-fmt", "targets": i});
columnDefs.push({
    "targets": i,
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return type === 'sort' ? data.replace(/.*\s/g,'') : data;
    }
});
```

Another way to ask my question is :

Is there a way to sort once by numbers and a second time by string? The first time they get sorted by numbers `PE 18, AH 18, PE 17, AH 17 ... etc` and the second time they get sorted by the first 2 strings so I would have a final result of `AH 18, PE 18, AH 17, PE 17 ... etc`

Comment: Try `.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(\d+)/g, '$2$1')`, you will comapre `18AH`, `17AH`, `16AH`, `15AH`, etc.

Comment: For a string like that : `"AH 18, AH 17, AH 16, ..."`I would have `split` on commas, then on whitespace, then sorted the big array like `array.sort(function(a,b) { return a[1] < b[1]; })`. Maybe less efficient than what @WiktorStribiżew proposed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post your comment as an answer, it's pure gold. Could you also please tell me what to do if the values are not in a string, but rather they are in an array, so you wouldn't be able to access them like that one after the other?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it works only for numbers with the same length.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, I added that as a disclaimer. I see that OP data only contains 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to work with numbers of the same length** (and the input data shows you have 2-digit numbers only), you may use

```
.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)\s+(\d+)/g, '$2$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gSh6Tv/1).

**Details**

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - capturing group 1: one or more ASCII letters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more digits.

The `$2$1` replacement pattern swaps the groups while removing the whitespace in between, so you end up comparing `18AH`, `17AH`, `16AH`, `15AH`,  etc.

Comment: But how do you sort the numbers descending with the letters ascending? A straight compare of strings won't work?

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips I understand this is what OP expects.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the strings and take the number part for numerical sorting first and then sort by characters.

```js
const split = s => s.split(' ');

var array = ['AH 18', 'AH 17', 'AH 16', 'AH 15', 'PE 18', 'PE 17', 'PE 16', 'PE 15'];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = split(a),
        bb = split(b);
    return bb[1] - aa[1] || aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0]);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "AH 18, AH 17, AH 16, AH 15, PE 18, PE 17, PE 16, PE 15";
var output = data.replace(/\s*/g,'').split(",").sort();
print(output);
print (bhavya(data,'sort','bhavya','meta'));

function bhavya( data, type, row, meta ) {
    return type === 'sort' ? data.replace(/\s*/g,'').split(",").sort() : data;
}
```

I tested the above code and I think this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you can do something like this perhaps:

```js
var data = 'AH 18, AH 17, AH 16, AH 15, PE 18, PE 17, PE 16, PE 15'.split(',').map(e => e.trim());
console.log("Original Data");
console.log(data);

var sortedByNumber = data.sort((a,b) => b.split(" ")[1] - a.split(" ")[1])
console.log("sortedByNumber");
console.log(sortedByNumber);

var sortedByString = data.sort((a,b) => (a.split(" ")[0]).localeCompare(b.split(' ')[0]))
console.log("sortedByString & sortedByNumber");
console.log(sortedByString);
```

Comment: It should return both data at the same time sorted together, not separately :)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Last array is both `sorted-by-number` (in reverse order) and `sorted-by-string` at same time. This is just a step-by-step demonstration

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
var items = ['AH 18', 'AH 17', 'AH 16', 'AH 15', 'PE 18', 'PE 17', 'PE 16', 'PE 15'];
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a_split = a.split(/\s+/);
    var b_split = b.split(/\s+/);
    if (a_split[1]>b_split[1]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a_split[1]==b_split[1]) {
        if (a_split[0]>b_split[0]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
alert(items);
```